# Kubernetes - imagePullSecrets deployment authorization failure

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to deploy a Kubernetes container by pulling an image from a remote registry (quay.io). While it works perfectly when deploying a pod, there is an unexpected problem with quay authorization when deploying it as a deployment. Don't know what misconfiguration in the yaml is causing the issue. Anyway, here's the working pod yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: private-reg
spec:
  containers:
  - name: private-reg-container
    image: quay.io/xxx/yyy
    imagePullPolicy: Always
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: test-secret
```

and here's the not working deployment yaml:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: random-name-deployment
  namespace: test-ns
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: random-name
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: random-name
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Always
      containers:
      - name: random-name
        image: quay.io/xxx/yyy
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: 10Mi
            cpu: 0.1
          limits:
            memory: 10Mi
            cpu: 0.1
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/config/config.yaml
          name: random-name-config
          subPath: config.yaml
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: test-secret
      volumes:
      - name: random-name-config
        configMap:
          name: random-name-config
```

It fails with an error:

```
kubectl describe:
Failed to pull image "quay.io/xxx/yyy": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: unauthorized: access to the requested resource is not authorized
```

However the secret seems to be loaded properly (and the secret has not changed in between deploying the pod and deployment - in the first scenario authorization works like a charm):

```
kubectl get -o yaml:
(...)
imagePullSecrets:
  - name: test-secret
```

What do I do wrong? Any sugestions will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: After some testing found that it's namespace that's causing the issue. So when "namespace: test-ns" is deleted, the deployment succeeds. However I'm still not sure why is that so and how can I use namespace other than default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem - my secret was deployed in DEFAULT namespace, not TEST-NS, as it should be. 
If anyone wanted to check for all secrets and their namespaces:

```
kubectl get secrets --all-namespaces
```

Funny though, that Kubectl never logged that the secret cannot be found - such info would be very helpful :(

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you did not provide commands you used. You probably forgot to add --namespace flag during POD deploying.

In Kubernetes any command like create, run, explain, describe, get ... etc automatically refers to **default** namespace, until you will specify another.

So if you will use 
`kubectl apply -f <pod.yaml>` pod will be created in **default** namespace. But if you will use `kubectl apply -f <pod.yaml> -n test` pod will be created in **test** namespace.

You can always verify what is contained in specified namespace

```
kubectl get all --namespace <namespace_name>
```

[Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/namespaces-walkthrough/) you can find for what namespaces are.

In addition, to debuggig very helpful commands are 
`kubectl describe pod <pod_name> -n <namespace>` `kubectl describe deployment <name> -n <namespace>` or `kubeclt get events -n <namespace>`